# add images to bxslider from javascript function

Tags: bxslider

I am using bxslider in modal popup and although I append image in bxslider div, the images are not displayed. When I hardcode the images in list tag in bxslider div it is working. So whats the fix for this issue. I need to add images to bxslider from javascript function

Here is the code

```
       function slideimage( ) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'someurl',


            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response.d, function (index, element) {

                    var im = 'the image.png';



                    $("#bxsliderShowImage").append("<li><img alt='' src='"+im+"' height='100' width='100'/></li>");


                });     }        });

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 1,

            slideWidth: 360,
            slideMargin: 10
        });
    }
```

html code

<--Modal popup body begins-->

```
  <ul class="bxslider" runat="server" id="bxsliderShowImage" visible="true" style="height: 200px">
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding slides (in your case a slide is a `<li>`) dynamically, then you'll need to reload bxSlider each time. There's a method from bxSlider's API called [**`reloadSlider`**](http://bxslider.com/options#reloadSlider). To use it you need to change how you instantiate bxSlider:

```
var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   slideWidth: 360,
   pager: false
});
```

Then on your function you use it there:

```
$("#bxsliderShowImage").append("<li><img alt='' src='"+im+"' height='100' width='100'/></li>");
bx.reloadSlider({
   slideWidth: 540,
   slideMargin: 10
});
```

When you reload, remember to include your options and/or change them, otherwise you'll just have defaults.

bxSlider's reloading is flaky, you're better off hardcoding the slide (i.e. `<li>`) inside the modal and then appending just the `<img>` or better yet, just change the `src` instead. bxSlider's load times are centered around loading of images and it's what makes or breaks it, so take a look at this option: [**`preloadImages`**](http://bxslider.com/options#preloadImages)

Comment: but reload slider is used when you want to add more slides after page is loaded and some preloaded images are displayed. But I wanted to add images from ajax response without hardcoding any image tags

Comment: I suggest that you hardcode the `<li>` at the very lest. When bxSlider loads, it does calculations on `.bx-wrapper` and `.bx-viewport`  height which is determined while wrapping around the `<li>` and `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.Need to append the li to modal id Posting it if some one need help.

```
 function slideimage() {

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            data: "{'requestId':'" + requestid + "'}",

            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response.d, function (index, element) {


                   var li = $("<li>").append("<img src='"+element.ImageName+"' width='400' height='400'/>");
                   $("#myModal ul").append(li);


                });
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                    minSlides: 1,

                    slideWidth: 360,
                    slideMargin: 10
                });
                }
        });

    }
```